# Monitor a folder for a new file using powershell but ignore new folders

Tags: powershell

I have this little script I made that monitors my music folder for new files and moves them into the respective artists folder. If that folder does not exist it creates it and then moves the mp3/flac/m4a file into the newly created folder. The only problem is that when it creates this new folder that also triggers an ObjectEvent in the script so then it starts acting goofy. Is is possible to change the script so that it only triggers an event when new files are added, not new folders?

```
###Load taglib
$TagLib = "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\taglib-sharp.dll"

#Load it into Powershell
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile($TagLib)

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { Write-Host "Recieved Event"
            $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            $media = [TagLib.File]::Create(($path))
            $artists = [string]$media.Tag.Artists
            Write-Host $artists
            Write-Host $logline
            Write-Host $path
            Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value $logline
            Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value $artists
            if(!(Test-Path -Path "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists" )){
                New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists"
                Write-Host "New folder created"
                Start-Sleep -s 2
            }
            Move-Item -Path "$path" -Destination "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists"
            Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value "moved"
          }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {
sleep 2 
Write-Host "Monitoring"
}
```

Comment: take a look at the `.NotifyFilter` property. i _think_ that is what you need, but have not tested it. got that from here ... FileSystemWatcher Class (System.IO) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I saw the .Filter property & It seems like it only applies to one type of file. It doesnt seem like I can filter it out to .flac/.mp3/.m4a/.wav etc. The NotifyFilter property looks interesting though

Comment: just rewrite the action to check for folder ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcSet was very close and he pointed me in the right direction. Here is what I used:

```
###Load taglib
$TagLib = "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\taglib-sharp.dll"

#Load it into Powershell

[system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile($TagLib)

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { Write-Host "Received Event"
            $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            Write-Host $path
            if((Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Leaf)){ 
                Write-Host "FILE"
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                $media = [TagLib.File]::Create(($path))
                $artists = [string]$media.Tag.Artists
                Write-Host $artists
                Write-Host $logline
                Write-Host $path
                Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value $logline
                Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value $artists
                if(!(Test-Path -Path "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists" )){
                    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists"
                    Write-Host "New folder created"
                    Start-Sleep -s 2
                }
                Move-Item -Path "$path" -Destination "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists"
                Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value "moved"
                }
          }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action

#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Deleted" -Action $action
#Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Renamed" -Action $action
while ($true) {
sleep 2 
Write-Host "Monitoring"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the action to check if file or folder. `if((Get-ChildItem $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath -File))` Gets the item only if its a file.

```
###Load taglib
$TagLib = "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\taglib-sharp.dll"

#Load it into Powershell
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadfile($TagLib)

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = new-object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { Write-Host "Recieved Event"
            $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            if((Get-ChildItem $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath -File)){
                write-host "FILE"
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                $media = [TagLib.File]::Create(($path))
                $artists = [string]$media.Tag.Artists
                Write-Host $artists
                Write-Host $logline
                Write-Host $path
                Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value $logline
                Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value $artists
                if(!(Test-Path -Path "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists" )){
                    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists"
                    Write-Host "New folder created"
                    Start-Sleep -s 2
                }
                Move-Item -Path "$path" -Destination "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Leak\$artists"
                Add-content "F:\Music-10-12-2016\Scripts\log.txt" -value "moved"
            }
        }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
while ($true) {
    sleep 2 
    Write-Host "Monitoring"
}
```

Comment: Tried that. Didn't seem to work. Edited the script to Write-Host $path as well and you'll see that when it created the folder it received Event and still thought it was a file https://gyazo.com/93b1205126986486a15329cefa32aba4

Comment: @ark are you using a new powershell instance becuase i dont see you unregistering the event. If you use the same powershell instance then it will just register more and more events till you close powershell.